# How do I add all files to git lfs

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I have been trying to add my unity project to github, so am trying to use git lfs. Since I have found that a lot of my files are big, all of different file types, I want to know how I should add all files, not just one specific file type to it.

Comment: Did you try `git lfs track "*"`?

Comment: that works? wow tysm, but im not sure if it works, unsure how to check too

Comment: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs?tab=readme-ov-file#example-usage